# Oracle procedure param defined as .NUMBER, is it ok to pass it in as .INTEGER

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have two procedures in oracle which define a parameter differently, even though the underlying data is the same.  In code we represent it as an integer.

```
procedure GetByNum(..., vRegionID in number, ...)
procedure GetByInt(...., vRegionID in integer, ...)
```

In java we always define the field as an Integer (and in db too)

```
public Integer getRegionID() {
    return 100;
}
```

Is there a way to pass this (in java) `integer` to both procedures using the same `OracleTypes.*`?  We use a custom base wrapper around `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure` to call both of them.  Modifying the stored procedures is not allowed for right now, so all that is left is fixing up the java.

1. Can you pass `getRegionID` as `OracleTypes.NUMBER` to the `getByInt` proc?
2. Can you pass it as `OracleTypes.INTEGER` to `getByNum`, which expects `in number`?
3. Another, magical way?

This might seem simple, but I assume i'm not allowed to mangle parameters like this.  I hope thats not true!

*Edit:*

- Using `OracleTypes.INTEGER` to pass to `procedure ... (param in number)` worked
- Don't know if this is just environment specific though

Hoping for a definitive answer, so I can have them start using the new wrapper without worrying about an unforeseen issue.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I've had someone test passing it as `.integer` to the proc which expects `in number`, and it worked.  I'm hoping for a definitive answer in some way, though.  If this is expected to work, or maybe it's just on our setup that it happens to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTEGER` is a ANSI standard type, which [Oracle describes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#sthref83) as a subtype of `NUMBER` as `NUMBER(38)`. Therefore, anywhere that takes an `INTEGER` as a parameter should also accept a `NUMBER` so long as there are no fractional parts.

Comment: Is the converse true?  I was going to pass an int as `OracleTypes.INTEGER` to a `vPK in number` parameter, but I can certainly reverse that if it is safer.

Comment: @AndrewBacker, it should be. As `INTEGER` is a subtype of `NUMBER`, passing an integer to a number parameter is passing a subtype to a supertype and therefore should be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I know how sql server resolves these things, but I don't know how it works on this side.